# Shell script: How to loop run two programs?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I'm running an Ubuntu server to mine crypto. It's not a very stable coin yet and their main node gets disconnected sometimes. When this happens it crashes the program through fatal error.

At first I wrote a loop script so it would keep running after a crash and just try again after 15 seconds:

```
while true;

do ./miner <somecodetoconfiguretheminer> &&break;
sleep 15
done;
```

This works, but is inefficient. Sometimes the loop will keep running for 30 minutes until the main node is back up - which costs me 30 minutes of hashing power unused. So I want it to run a second miner for 15 minutes to mine another coin, then check the first miner again if its working yet.

So basically: Start -> Mine coin 1 ->  if crash -> Mine coin 2 for 15 minutes -> go to Start

I tried the script below but the server just becomes  unresponsive once the first miner disconnects:

```
while true;

do ./miner1 <somecodetoconfiguretheminer> &&break;
timeout 900 ./miner2 
sleep 15
done;
```

Ive read through several topics / questions on how &&break works, timeout works and how while true works but I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Instead of `while true; do cmd && break; ...` you can write `while ! cmd; do ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after trial and error - and some help - I found out that there is nothing wrong with my initial code. Timeout appears to behave differently on my linux instance when used in terminal than in a bash script. If used in Terminal it behaves as it should, it counts down and then kills the process it started. If used in bash however - it acts as if I typed 'sleep' and then after counting down stops.

Apparently this has to do with my Ubuntu instance (running on a VPS). Even though I installed latest versions of coreutils, have all the latest versions installed through apt-get update etc. This is the case for me on Digital Ocean as well as Google Compute.

The solution is to use the Timeout code as a function within the bash script, as found on another thread in stackoverflow. I named the function timeout2 as to not confuse the system in triggering the not properly working timeout command:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Executes command with a timeout
# Params:
#   $1 timeout in seconds
#   $2 command
# Returns 1 if timed out 0 otherwise
timeout2() {

     time=$1

     # start the command in a subshell to avoid problem with pipes
     # (spawn accepts one command)
     command="/bin/sh -c "$2""

     expect -c "set echo "-noecho"; set timeout $time; spawn -noecho 
$command; expect timeout { exit 1 } eof { exit 0 }"

    if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
        echo "Timeout after ${time} seconds"
    fi

}

while true;

do

./miner1 <parameters for miner> && break;
sleep 5
timeout2 300 ./miner2 <parameters for miner>
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution would be to run both of the programs all the time, and lower the priority of the less-preferred one.  On Linux and similar systems, that is:

```
nice -10 ./miner2loop.sh &
./miner1loop.sh
```

Then the scripts can be similar to your first one.

Comment: Thanks John, to check if I understand your suggestion correctly: does this mean that if the first miner would use no processing power (because it is looping into a dead node) the other miner will get more power - and as soon as the first miner connects again the second process moves to the back again? Or will the second miner use limited processing power no matter what the first miner is doing?

Comment: miner2 will probably use a bit of processing power even when miner1 is running.  But the point is to let the system schedule them as best it can.  Try it.